# How to delete "..." folder ？ Windows Platform

Tags: windows

Cmd "md ...\" create this folder on my disk.I can't delete it...

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you adding hyperlink, please provide meaningful description.

Comment: Try to run `rd "...\"` from cmd against that same folder name

Comment: Thx,This solved my problem@Seth

Answer (score 0):

Try Renaming the Unnamed Folder, if you can't then try changing access permission or you can also use deleting software to ease your Task.